# Why I'm getting different place in bing maps?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api

First I'm getting geocode using google API key, then find the route(direction) using the same address which is geocoded using BING Map, which is giving me different places.

Can anybody tell me what is a concern?

Comment: If you don't share your code with us and any relevant diagnostic information, how can we help you?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that the terms of use of both platforms do not allow mixing of API's.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that there is no single coordinate that uniquely represents an address. An address is an area and thus any coordinate within in its boundaries is valid. Additionally, many geocoders use interpolation to approximate the location of an address on a road as the actually property boundary data is not available in most countries.